# In ActionScript3 I cannot view a long text in TextInput

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textinput

Hi, I design a TextInput by using components in Flash, height=240 width=400. While I'm typing a long text, half of the text is cut out. How can i correct this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var _txt:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(_txt);
_txt.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
_txt.wordWrap = true;
_txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```

`autosize` will gives the flexible automatic sizing and alignment. and in your case do not set height for the textfield.

Comment: ok sir If i typed multi text,i cannot view the full text.If i scroll down then only i can view?how to Rectify this.

Comment: listChat.textField.wordWrap=true;  listChat.htmlText = chatText;

Comment: No sir agin it Looks like that.If i Scroll down then only i Can view the full text sir

Comment: u r using textInput component?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5643/discussion-between-leema-rose-and-benny-geo)

Answer (score 2):

you can make your textField multiline and make text wrapped like

```
txt.multiline=true;
txt.wordWrap=true;
txt.width=400;
```

Comment: ok sir If i typed multi text,i cannot view the full text.If i scroll down then only i can view?how to Rectify this.

Comment: do textfield autoSize="left" like txt.autoSize="left". it will solve problem

Comment: i tried txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT; if i use this line ,the text is Displayed correctly.But i Dynamically added the text.So the size length of the txt is moved depends on text.so my Design is looking bad

Answer (score 1):

it's as easy as

```
 yourTextField.wordWrap = true;
```

Comment: ok sir If i typed multi text,i cannot view the full text.If i scroll down then only i can view?how to Rectify this.